# Update select value if exists in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla

I have a problem, it doesn't update the value of 2 selects. The value is a numeric code and a string is stored in DB.

Here is my example in HTML:

```
<select id="jform_country" name="jform[country]" class="form-control required chzn-done">
    <option value="">Select country...</option>
    <option value="1012234" selected="selected">Name country 1</option>
    <option value="1012257">Name country 2</option>
</select>
<select id="jform_city" name="jform[city]" class="form-control required chzn-done">
    <option value="">Select city...</option>
    <option value="1982727" selected="selected">Name city 1</option>
    <option value="1982739">Name city 2</option>
</select>
```

I retrieve DB value with a function in php (getData). But here is my problem... I try to pass that variable from PHP to JavaScript, it seems to work correctly and I change the value of the select with jQuery. But when refreshing the page, in some cases it does not work correctly.

Here is my code in PHP and jQuery:

```
$data = $model->getData();
$country = $data->country;
$city = $data->city;
echo '<script>';
echo 'var selectcountry = '. json_encode($country) .';';
echo 'var selectcity = '. json_encode($city) .';';
echo '</script>';
```

And with jQuery I recieve those variables:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        setTimeout(function() {
            rescueValue(selectcountry, selectcity);
        }, 800);

        function rescueValue(selectcountry, selectcity) {

            if (selectcountry != null) {
                jQuery("#jform_country option:contains('"+ selectcountry +"')").attr("selected", "selected");
                jQuery("#jform_country").trigger("liszt:updated");
            }

            if (selectcity != null) {
                jQuery("#jform_city option:contains('"+ selectcity +"')").attr("selected", "selected");
                jQuery("#jform_city").trigger("liszt:updated");
            }
        }

    });
```

Could it be that it works asynchronously? I tried to put a `setTimeout` but still I don't solve it. How can I make it recover the PHP value and update it in a simple way (similar to this one)? Thanks!

Comment: *I retrieve DB value with a function in php (getData).*  How?  On page load?  Ajax?  What operation executes this logic?

Comment: The php variables 'country' and 'city' lack the dollar sign to initiate variables

Comment: Yes, on page load, sorry I did not specify it...

Comment: I edited php variables (it was a failure to copy the data, thanks @Rick Jelier)

Comment: Your logic is inside a document ready, so the DOM should be loaded, including the inline script that creates the variables, so they should exist.  Put a console.log immediately before the function call (`rescueValue(selectcountry, selectcity)`) and log the variables.  See what they log in the cases that you see the error.

Comment: Try to add a document.ready to the echo statement of the variables (so that var selectcountry = ' .  json_encode($country) .'; is surrounded by it?

Comment: If I try to add a document.ready in echo variables (PHP) and show a console.log it shows: 'ReferenceError: selectcountry is not defined'

Comment: So the javascript variable `selectcountry` that is generated by php and loaded into your `<script>` block is not accessible by your `jQuery` block?  Seems like a "variable scope" problem.  Can you check the browser's source code that is rendered by your coding atttempt?  Are you able to write all of your javascript into your jQuery block?  Then you could be sure that this is not a scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's more correct to set the value of the `select`, than finding the option value from the list to set it the `selected` attribute, which may not always work if, for example, there's already another option with the `selected` attribute.

You can use [jquery.val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the value directly.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        setTimeout(function() {
            rescueValue(selectcountry, selectcity);
        }, 800);

        function rescueValue(selectcountry, selectcity) {

            if (selectcountry != null) {
                jQuery("#jform_country").val(selectcountry).trigger("liszt:updated");
            }

            if (selectcity != null) {
                jQuery("#jform_city").val(selectcity).trigger("liszt:updated");
            }
        }

    });
```